# searching multiple words from a .tr file

Tags: grep

I need to calculate the received packets from `.tr` file. The problem is that one string is necessary for me but some unnecessary events are also counted.

So I want a solution.

```
line1: r 0.500000000 1 RTR — 0 cbr 210 [0 0 0 0] ——- [1:0 5:0 32 0] [0] 0 0 
line2: r 0.501408175 3 RTR — 0 AODV 48 [0 ffffffff 1 800] ——- [1:255 -1:255 30 0] [0x2 1 1 [5 0] [1 4]] (REQUEST)
```

I want only *line 1* but as I am searching for `‘^r’` only so both files are returned. Please help me how can I search the line where 2 patterns are needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to match more than one expression at a time, or to return results if one of the expressions exist.

- `OR` alike - if *foo* **or** *bar* matches:

  ```
  grep -e "foo|bar" file
  ```
- `AND` alike - if *foo* **and** *bar* matches:

  ```
  grep "foo" file | grep "bar"
  ```

As you need 2 patterns, I will go for the latest.  But still, I think you may improve your question putting an example of what you expect your code to return, and what exact command are you currently using.

You may also define a `grep` command to find the occurrences of *foo*, but that does not include *bar*.  Maybe that is easier, depending on what you need.

```
grep "foo" file | grep -v "bar"
```